# How to show a Game Scene that has a Sprite Kit Scene under one View Controller Menu?

Tags: ios, swift

I have an app that has three different menu options, however whenever I attempt to add a game scene it either crashs or does not function.

Thread 1: "-[SKScene _cachedTraitCollectionIsValid]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x106e2d5d0"

Occurs in app delegate.

Or

Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

which occurs on the player = self.childNode line.

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
    
    var player = SKSpriteNode()
    
    var touchLocation = CGPoint()
    
    override func didMove(to view: SKView){
        player = self.childNode(withName: "player") as! SKSpriteNode


    }
    override func touchesBegan (_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        
        for touch in touches {
            touchLocation = touch.location(in: self)
            player.position.x = touchLocation.x
            
        }
    }
    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set <UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        
        for touch in touches {
            touchLocation = touch.location(in: self)
            player.position.x = touchLocation.x
        }
    }

}
```

The code in the main storyboard is

```
    var scene: GameScene?

    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()
        self.view = SKView()
        self.view.bounds = UIScreen.main.bounds
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        setupScene()
    }

    func setupScene() {
        if let view = self.view as? SKView, scene == nil {
            let scene = GameScene(size: view.bounds.size)
            view.presentScene(scene)
            self.scene = scene
        }
    }

    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

Maybe I'm doing something horribly wrong, I'm trying to piece together multiple tutorials I am very new to this. Any help would be apprecated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like problem is in this line:

```
player = self.childNode(withName: "player") as! SKSpriteNode
```

You are trying to retrieve some node called "player".
But this player was not added to the scene.

You are creating the player:

```
var player = SKSpriteNode()
```

And after that you need add player to the scene:

```
self.addChild(player)
```

instead of trying to retrieve and replace variable with value that doesn't exist:

```
player = self.childNode(withName: "player") as! SKSpriteNode
```

Comment: Thank you, this has made the error go away, however now that view shows nothing, just a blank screen, insteaad of the square that I would like to move around.